# Flutter Androit | Firebase Authentication Persistance with Firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I wan't to persist authentication state of an user registered in Firebase Auth. The user has data in Firestore DB.

My final attempt :

*main.dart*

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamProvider<AppUser?>.value(
      value: AuthenticationService().user,
      initialData: null,
      child: const ....
    );
  }
```

*home.dart*

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var user = Provider.of<AppUser?>(context);
    print(user);
    Home.user = user;
    ...
  }
```

*authentication.dart*

```dart
class AuthenticationService {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final FirebaseFirestore _db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  final CollectionReference _usersCollection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');

  Stream<AppUser?> get user {
    return _auth.authStateChanges().map((firebaseUser) {
      AppUser? user;
      _usersCollection.doc(firebaseUser!.uid).get().then((DocumentSnapshot userSnapshot) {
        user = _toAppUser(firebaseUser, userSnapshot);
      });
      return user;
    });
  }
}
```

But with this code, the get user is always null, even just afte logging in

Comment: The code for detecting auth state changes looks fine to me at first glance. --- "the get user is always null" Can you clarify a bit what that means? I.e.: if you step through the code line by line in a debugger, which is the first line that doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: Sorry it was night and i was tired ;) 
I know that the Home.user is null, even after logging. So i think the getter for user (in authentication.dart) returns null (maybe an asynchronous problem but i can't make that method async)

Comment: Aha, I see what you mean now. Well, loading data is an asynchronous operation, and you'll have to deal with that. Are you sure the return type isn't `Stream<Future<AppUser?>>` or that you want to use `yield return`?

Comment: The returns type need to be AppUser if i want pass it to the streamprovider so i think my method need to be synchronous

Answer (score 0):

So after dozens of changes, the following code is "working" :

*main.dart*

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    cart.cache();
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: 'CharleMi\'App',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Home(),
    );
  }
```

*home.dart*

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<User?>(
        stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            AuthenticationService.delegate(snapshot.data).then((user) {
              if (user != null) {
                Home.user = user;
              }
            });
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            print(snapshot.error);
          }
          return ....
```

*authentication.dart*

```dart
static Future<AppUser?> delegate(User? data) async {
    return AuthenticationService()._toAsyncAppUser(data, null);
  }

Future<AppUser?> _toAsyncAppUser(User? user) async {
    AppUser _user = AppUser(uid: user!.uid);
    var exists = await _user.init(); //Return true, get vars from firestore
    if (exists) {
      return _user; //Returned here when logging in (because exists)
    }
    return null;
  }
```